# Loading image with ionic cordova emulate android –lc

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I am using the command ionic cordova run android --c . Images loaded from my web server are shown correctly like `<ion-img src="/accountfiles/ac_{{accountid.ac_id}}/students/student_{{student.id}}.png"></ion-img>`
But images from android emulator storage do not 
`<ion-img src="file:///data/data/io.ionic.starter/files/1526441731794.jpg" style="width: 100%" ></ion-img>`

if I remove --c 
this does not work
`<ion-img src="/accountfiles/ac_{{accountid.ac_id}}/students/student_{{student.id}}.png"></ion-img>`

but this does `<ion-img src="file:///data/data/io.ionic.starter/files/1526441731794.jpg" style="width: 100%" ></ion-img>` . 
Why is this happening? How can I make them work both at the same time on my android emulator and hopefully on my device?

> Update

when ever I run 
`ionic cordova run android` the following piece of code works and shows the image returned from the function pathForImage
`<img [src]="pathForImage(lastImage)" style="width: 100%" [hidden]="curImage === null">`

however if I run 
`ionic cordova emulate android --lc` the image is not displayed but `console.log(lastImage)` prints the url of the image which is `file:///data/data/io.ionic.starter/files/1526441731794.jpg`. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? can I move on and believe that this will work?